# Customer specific Firebase storage

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have an Flutter app that use Firebase as backend. Initially, a Firebase project and a collection is created to store data from different customers using the app. A key field "Customer" is use to separate the data among different users in the big pool.

In order to enhance the security and customise the billing incure in Firebase, I would like to separate different customer with their own Firebase account/project/database setup, the process is:

Whenever a new customer install the app and run it at the first time, the app will ask the customer to create his/her firebase account and then pass the account information to the app. Then, the app can consume the customer specific firebase for their private data storage.

Is there any experts can give me a hints how can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to create new firebase account for every user? First of all this is not possible because you need to initialize a firebase project to your flutter project when you build the app, secondly they won't have any relation with one another.

Comment: I believe you're asking about *multi-tenant* - each customer would have their own separate 'space' within Firebase and the data is totally separated from other customers. A customer would have their own users; database etc. Firebase doesn't do that very well (or at all, really). I believe there was some work being done to provide multitenancy but not sure where that stands. Perhaps a firebaser has some input?

Comment: Thanks!  It is exactly what I want.  Is there any further input from Firebaser?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#user_private?

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically create a project you can use this GCP [`create API`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) and then link it to Firebase with [this API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/workflow_set-up-and-manage-project?platform=ios#add-firebase). But they'd need an existing account already.

Alternatively you can have them create the account and project on their own through the console, and then use the [`list` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/list) to get a list of projects, have them pick one, and [get the project config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects#FirebaseProject).

All of these are pretty raw APIs though, so you'll have to play around a bit to get the calls exactly right. Many of the REST APIs will have an API explorer link, which is typically helpful in figuring it out.

Comment: I think they are asking about multitenancy (?!?!?)

Comment: It seemed to me that OP wants to not put multiple tenants in a single project, but let each tenant pick their own Firebase project. My answer shows how to do that (it's the same approach Glitch and StackBlitz use for their Firebase integrations), though I'd usually indeed put multi-tenants in a single project myself.